# What happened to the Doomsday Machine after the Enterprise destroyed it?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

The crew of the *USS Enterprise* destroyed [the Doomsday Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Doomsday_Machine_(Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series)) by using another damaged starship as a bomb. That destroyed the internal guts of the machine, but left the shell.

**What happened to the shell?**

Did the Federation send a science team to study it? Was it later destroyed?

Comment: Ha, does fanfic count?

Comment: It was purchased by General Mills and towed into Earth orbit for use as an advertising sign for Bugles snacks.

Comment: You'll go down a bottomless rabbit hole if you look for followup and continuity in the Star Trek universe.  For example, on TNG they found a *Dyson Sphere*!  No followup, no exposition about the species that created it, no exploitation of the technology.  There are *many* other examples.  It's best to watch TOS and TNG as if there is only one Star Trek episode, and that's the one you're watching.  DS9 and VOY tried harder but still are a mess.

Comment: @KyleJones There was a followup book that had the *Enterprise* and at least one other ship (captained by a Horta!) return to the sphere for further investigation (which ended with the sphere going bye-bye, tying up that plot hole), at least.

Comment: I don't quite understand this outrage about "not following up".  The USS Enterprise and its heroic crew wouldn't be wasted for the years-long techno-archaeology required to study these amazing artifacts.  That's just not in their mission statement.  They boldly explore, finding amazing things for a fleet of science vessels to do the "following up", while they move onward.  And then either 1) good methodical science took place, or 2) a further bout of excitement occurred, but since the Alpha Quadrant is huge, the second adventure did not involve the Enterprise, but another Starfleet vessel.

Comment: *I don't quite understand this outrage about "not following up".* - @Blaze  What "outrage"? I don't see any outrage here. Just a question and some comments, one of which contains a possible answer.

Answer (score 2):

**In canon, it's [still floating lifelessly in space.](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Planet_killer)**

There are , however, two instances in books (considered apocrypha) where the original machine makes it a return. A short story in Kevin Lauderdale's *Constellations* reveals that the original was dragged to a top secret Starfleet research facility for further study.

Peter David's book, *Before Dishonor*, has the machine stored in a museum where

> it is restored to working condition and used to destroy a Borg Cube attacking Earth.

Comment: more than just those two references to the machines: https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Doomsday_machine